# VB.NET Charts - Going throught every database row

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've the following database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uim8V.png)

And I want this information on a chart, I was able to get the first row but it repeats itself a lot of times and I don't have any idea how to make it going throught to the other rows.

I've the following code:

```
Public Class consutar
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open("Select * from error", BdSQL, 1, 3)

        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            'MsgBox(rs("nom_error").Value.ToString)
            grafico.Series("Nombre Errores").Points.AddXY(rs("nom_error").Value.ToString, rs("nombre_error").Value.ToString)
        Next fld

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to loop through the recordset; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ArnovanBoven thanks I just add (inside of the for): `If rs.EOF = False Then
                grafico.Series("Nombre Errores").Points.AddXY(rs("nom_error").Value.ToString, rs("nombre_error").Value.ToString)
                rs.MoveNext()
            End If`

Comment: You really need to move to ADO.net for new code.